# Communication Exception in WCF via WP8

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, windows-phone-8

I have a simple WCF service deployed on localhost in IIS. I was able to access it from my windows phone app in the first. But after connecting to a different Wifi network at home I am unable to access it via new local IP. I have tried republishing the service. I also have tried reconfiguring the service reference in WP8 app. While adding the reference the add service wizard does detect the WCF service deployed on a new IP (The local IP address naturally changes after the laptop is connected to a different network). But whenever a simple Authenticate function is called from the device, it shows an exception. Stackoverflow would not let me post the screenshot because of low reputation, but the exact exception message is:

> 'An exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occured in System.ServiceModel.ni.dll but was not handled in user code'
>   Additional Information: The remote server returned an error: NotFound.

This exception occurs in Reference.cs file over the second line of following function:

```
public string EndAuthenticateCustomer(System.IAsyncResult result) {
            object[] _args = new object[0];
            string _result = ((string)(base.EndInvoke("AuthenticateCustomer", _args, result)));
            return _result;
        }
```

I am running the app in debugging mode. If I run the installed app on my phone and try to access the service then it simply crashes. This is a part of my final year project. So I would be working in university as well as home which means the local IP on which the service is hosted will often change. I have looked for this exact problem over and over again with no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure your WCF service is correctly configured, and up and running?

Comment: Yes I am sure it is up and running. I can access it though my PC's local IP address in a web browser. Even the references are correctly configured and updated.

Comment: From your exception it seems that your client is not able connect to your service. The issue may lie in your firewall blocking off other connected devices maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would still have to provide the code where you instatiate the service, but you can configure the services IP when you instantiate it:

```
        // at home
        //const string ipAddress = "192.168.200.111";
        // at school
        const string ipAddress = "192.168.100.118";
        string address = string.Format("http://{0}/MobileService/DataService.svc", ipAddress);
        var mobileDataService = new MobileDataServiceClient(new MobileDataServiceClient.EndpointConfiguration(), new EndpointAddress(address));
```

You would have to change the IP depending on the network you are in. Alternatively you could push it to a server that has a constant IP e.g. Azure (if that is an option).